# Power BI - Date Slicer (yyyy/mm/dd) - How to create a line chart monthly for all 12 months in the selected 'date' year?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the need - for useability reasons - to create only one 'date' slicer dropdown, which defaults to 'Today' via dynamic column in the Date dimension.

Then this one slicer is used to compute the value in a Card to SUM only the currently selected day's sales. And then for the entire calendar year show sales for each month. How can I code the latter?

[image]